# Implementing Enumerations interface to Print a class Object

Tags: java, collections, interface, enumeration

This is my source code. I want to traverse a `Vector` using the `Enumeration` interface. If I simply traverse the `Vector`, I get hash codes of objects and if I implement interface `Enumeration` on the class `Student` I'm asked to override the `nextElement()` method. Can anyone tell me a way of overridding this method so that I get elements of class (i.e. name, r_num and cgpa) and not the hashcodes of objects?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student implements Enumeration {
    private String name;
    private int r_num;
    private float cgpa;

    Student() {
    }

    Student(String name,int r_num,float cgpa)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.r_num=r_num;
        this.cgpa=cgpa;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the r_num
     */
    public int getR_num() {
        return r_num;
    }

    /**
     * @param r_num the r_num to set
     */
    public void setR_num(int r_num) {
        this.r_num = r_num;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cgpa
     */
    public float getCgpa() {
        return cgpa;
    }

    /**
     * @param cgpa the cgpa to set
     */
    public void setCgpa(float cgpa) {
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vector<Student> studentList = new Vector<>();
        Enumeration en;
        System.out.println("Enter Students' Name, Roll Number and CGPA");
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        char ch;

        do
        {
            int x=0;
            String s= in.next();
            int r= in.nextInt();
            float c= in.nextFloat();
            studentList.add(new Student(s,r,c));
            System.out.println("Enter another student's record?(y/n)");
            ch= in.next().charAt(0);
        }
        while(ch=='y'|| ch=='Y');
        System.out.println("List of Students: ");
        en = studentList.elements();
        while(en.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(en.nextElement());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Object nextElement() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Enumeration was replaced by Iterator in 1998.  Perhaps it is time to let go of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to traverse a `Vector` using the `Enumeration` interface.

No, you don't. You want to traverse a `List`, quite possibly an `ArrayList`, using the `Iterable` and `Iterator` interfaces. `Vector` and `Enumeration` are very old fashioned and almost certainly not what you want.

> If I simply traverse the `Vector`, I get hash codes of objects.

No, you don't. You get the actual objects. The problem is, your class doesn't override the `toString()` method, so when you print them out with `System.out.println` you get the default `toString()` format of `java.lang.Object`, which looks like `Student@DEADBEEF`.

Add a `toString()` method to `Student`, such as:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + r_num + " " cgpa;
}
```

If you really want to implement `Enumeration`, take a look at the source code that comes with the JDK to see how classes like `Vector` and `ArrayList` implement it. But it doesn't make sense to have `Student` implement it, since a `Student` isn't a collection of anything that you can enumerate.

Comment: Your first paragraph is vague. What if the OP specifically wants to use `Vector`?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would make what I said vague, although it could potentially make it incorrect. It seems clear enough from the context (we've seen a complete program) that the OP simply wants a collection of `Student`s, and isn't interested in the synchronization of `Vector`, but if that is what is truly desired, OP can ignore my recommendation and continue using `Vector`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanx now my Source Code is Running Perfectly. :)

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I had to specifically use Enumeration interface. I m new to this concept. I've seen enums  implemented by vectors, hence used the same in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you didn't override `toString()`, and so the call to print out the next element is using the default `toString()`, which prints out a relatively unhelpful message (i.e. the "hashcode" you're referring to, or the class name, an at sign, and the location of the object in memory).

Furthermore, you shouldn't be implementing `Enumeration` if your `Student` class does not represent something which can be iterated over.